# How to replace string values across multiple columns with values from a single column in separate dataframe

Tags: r

I'm trying to replace some values across multiple columns of a dataframe by matching them to other values in a single list:

```
#data frame of medical codes
code1 <- c('T432', 'T432', 'T432', 'T432')
code2 <- c('T492', 'T405', 'T424', 'J81')
code3 <- c('T509', '', 'R99', '')
code_df <- data.frame(code1, code2, code3)

#data frame of code description
description <- c('Cholera', 'Salmonella', 'Typhoid ', 'Psoriasis', 'Other malady', 'Fever', 'Acute Pain')
code <- c('T432', 'T832', 'T405', 'T424', 'J81', 'R99', 'T492' )
description_df <- data.frame(description, code)

#me trying to replace the code with the corresponding description
code_df[1:3] <- sapply(unlist(code_df[1:3]), function(x) description_df$description[x == description_df][2])
```

This is just producing a code_df where all values are NA and no descriptions are populated.

Desired result:

```
Code1       Code2            Code3
Cholera     Acute Pain       
Cholera     Typhoid 
Cholera     Psoriasis        Fever
Cholera     Other malady
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `match`:

```r
code_df[] <- description_df$description[match(unlist(code_df), description_df$code)]

    code1        code2 code3
1 Cholera   Acute Pain  <NA>
2 Cholera     Typhoid   <NA>
3 Cholera    Psoriasis Fever
4 Cholera Other malady  <NA>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `tidyverse`

```
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)
code_df %>%
   mutate(across(everything(), ~ deframe(description_df[2:1])[.x]))
```

-output

```
    code1        code2 code3
1 Cholera   Acute Pain  <NA>
2 Cholera     Typhoid   <NA>
3 Cholera    Psoriasis Fever
4 Cholera Other malady  <NA>
```

---

Or in `base R`

```
code_df[] <-  with(description_df, 
      setNames(description, code))[as.matrix(code_df)]
```